# Variegated Arboricola shrubs leaves wilting

Tags: diagnosis, weed-control, shrubs, herbicide, wilt

What can I do to help this Variegated Arboricola to grow healthy and stop wilting?

[image: Variegated Arboricola]

I am in Southern Florida. I was spraying my lawn with [Ortho® Weed B Gon® Weed Killer For Lawns Ready-To-Spray2](http://www.ortho.com/smg/goprod/ortho-weed-b-gon-max-lawn-weed-killer-hose-sprayer/prod70200) which is near these plants. Prior to the spraying/treatment the plant was looking far better. The leaves were sticking straight out rather than drooping. I am not sure what to do now to nurse them back to health.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Hi Ryan! I see you've been around the network but haven't posted here yet, so welcome! Just to clarify, were those plants doing fine until you sprayed weed killer on your nearby lawn? Did anything else change, like amount of water, sun, or anything in its own soil? Thanks!

Comment: @Sue that is a very good point. I updated my question and hopefully that provides enough information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The active ingredient of the herbicide used is Dicamba Mecoprop. It also affects broad leaf shrubs and trees.  From this [pdf](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_o93voJXLAhVCKx4KHUYLCakQFgg6MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjoa.isa-arbor.com%2Frequest.asp%3FJournalID%3D1%26ArticleID%3D1944%26Type%3D2&usg=AFQjCNHVTh8sTE2XNHVUdC6HFebswOUAAw&sig2=U7oUXuOaGeql5EeS6Jb0WQ) by the International Society of Arborists

> Once the material is absorbed there is no treatment to alleviate the symptoms
>   except to avoid watering and fertilization. Removal of the tree should 
>   wait the second year because often a tree will recover
>   and over a period of one to two years will regain its former appearance.

Although this article is about trees there are many other references with the same conclusions:

- do not water
- do not fertilize
- wait and see
- "[most woody plants will tolerate the injury and recover](https://pace.oregonstate.edu/courses/sites/default/files/resources/pdf/diagnosing-and-preventing-herbicide-injury-to-trees.pdf)"